# Why can I only see IPv4 packets in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, ipv4, packet-sniffers, packets

I have installed the new Wireshark 2.2.7. The problem is that when I run a capture on my Wifi, the only packets I can see are from protocol `0x0800` and are of IPv4.

[image: screenshot]

I have all protocols enabled, and I run the capture on my Wifi with no filters.

What can I do to see all of the protocols and the other packets ?

Comment: In the IP header, the `Protocol` field is not the IP version field.  The protocol indicates UDP, TCP, etc.  There is a separate `Version` field to indicate IPv4 vs IPv6.  In any case, the fact that you are only seeing IPv4 packets means you are likely capturing only on your Wifi's IPv4 interface, not its IPv6 interface.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Wi-Fi's IPv4 interface" our a "Wi-Fi's IPv6 interface"... IPv4 and IPv6 run over the same interface.